# Make a triangle SliderComponentShape have rounded corners in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a triangle which shows above a slider based on it's value:

```
class TriangleShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  TriangleShape({
    required this.color, // Added color parameter
  });

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size.fromRadius(12); // Adjust the size as needed
  }

  Color color;

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final path = Path();

    // Adjust the coordinates based on the slider value
    final double yOffset = -10.0 + value * 4.0; // You can adjust the multiplier as needed
    const double halfSide = 7.0; // Adjust the halfSide as needed

    path.moveTo(center.dx - halfSide, center.dy + yOffset - halfSide);
    path.lineTo(center.dx + halfSide, center.dy + yOffset - halfSide);
    path.lineTo(center.dx, center.dy + yOffset);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
}
```

and I call it like so in the SliderTheme:

```
data: SliderThemeData(
  trackHeight: 0.0,
  thumbShape: TriangleShape(color: ingredientRatingColor(widget.attributeValue.round())),
```

How can I make it so the triangle have rounded corners and add corner radius and still remain a SliderComponenetShape?

Comment: see [roundPolygon](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L24)